# triple integral - ecliptic coordinate

Tags: integration, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I need to find the $V$ by triple  integral.
the limits from up is (1) - ecliptic cone.
and from dwon - (2) - elepsoide.

$$(1) \ \ \ \ z=-\sqrt{3x^2+5y^2}$$
$$(2) \ \ \ \ {3 \over 10}x^2+5y^2+{z^2 \over 3}=8$$

[image]

I try to use:
$x=5r\cos\theta$
$y=3r\sin\theta$
$z=z$

but I'm not sure it's good coordinate and I can't find the limit.

Comment: I don't think these should be called [elliptic coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system). If this is what you meant by ecliptic coordinates. This is rather (almost) [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) for $x,y$.

Comment: sorry, you right

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the volume looks like - can you be a little more descriptive?

Comment: I need to fine the volume of a shape by using triple integral with the limits I mentioned above. using Jacobian etc, so I need to fint the limits for the integral

Comment: So you want to find the volume outside the cone but inside the ellipsoid?

Comment: just the volume blocks by these 2 limits from up and down.
i dont understand what do you mean inside outside

Comment: @user1816377: I added a plot. If you don't like it remove it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This one is obviously a little messy, but there is a simple methodology by which the volume may be reduced to a single integral.  The idea is to compute the cross sectional area $A(z)$ for each value of $z$ in the volume, and then integrate over $z$ to get the volume.

First, we needs the bounds in $z$.  This is done by observing that the relevant $z$ vertex of the ellipsoid is at $z=-2 \sqrt{6}$.  In between, it should be clear that each cross section is an intersection of two ellipses centered at the origin.  The first has equation

$$\frac{x^2}{z^2/3} + \frac{y^2}{z^2/5} = 1$$

the other has equation

$$\frac{x^2}{\frac{80}{3} \left(1-\frac{z^2}{24}\right)} + \frac{y^2}{\frac{8}{5} \left(1-\frac{z^2}{24}\right)}=1$$

There are three different scenarios: one in which the first ellipse is entirely within the second, one in which the second is entirely within the first, and one in which they stick out of each other.  The intervals in $z$ where these different scenarios occur may be determined by equating the vertices in $x$ and $y$, respectively, in the first and second ellipses.  The result is three intervals in $z$:

- I: $z \in \left[-2 \sqrt{6},-\sqrt{\frac{240}{13}}\right]$
- II: $z \in \left[-\sqrt{\frac{240}{13}},-\sqrt{6}\right]$
- III: $z \in \left[-\sqrt{6},0\right]$

In interval I, the area is simply the area of the ellipsoid cross section:

$$A(z) = \frac{8 \sqrt{6}}{3} \pi \left(1-\frac{z^2}{24}\right)$$

(Note that I used the formula $A=\pi a b$ as the area of the ellipse $(x^2/a^2)+(y^2/b^2)=1$.)

In interval III, the area is simply the area of the conical cross section:

$$A(z) = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{15}} z^2$$

That leaves interval II, in which there is an intersection:

[image: ellipses]

The cross sectional area is broken up into 2 pieces: one bounded by the first ellipse at the sides, and another bounded by the second ellipse in the center.  The area is then

$$4 \int_{x_0(z)}^{z/\sqrt{3}} dx \: \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{z^2-3 y^2} + 2 \int_{-x_0(z)}^{x_0(z)} dx \: \sqrt{\frac{8}{5}} \sqrt{1-\frac{z^2}{24}-3 \frac{x^2}{80}}$$

where

$$x_0(z)=\frac{\sqrt{z (z+3)-24}}{3 \sqrt{\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{10}}}$$

Comment: To make the computations easier I thought of making a change of variables so that the ellipsoid becomes a sphere, and modify the elliptical cone accordingly. I am not sure if this is of much help though.

Comment: @AméricoTavares: worth a try; this problem is a bit sadistic to be just a homework problem IMO.

Comment: That's right! BTW I gave a look at the solution you posted in your blog to the "3 cylinders" challenge.

Comment: @AméricoTavares: Oh, terrific, glad someone's looking at it.  Was the solution understandable?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't check every detail. It is amazing how fast you posted it. I had the idea of just computing the volume in the 1st octant and multiply the result by 8, but I am very slow.

Comment: @AméricoTavares: really?  I didn't think so; I thought I was taking my sweet time.  The blog was easy for me to set up because it is just a sub-blog from one I already have set up, and it has MathJax loaded. Hopefully it will serve its purpose as an eventual place for me to refer to the techniques I use to solve the coolest problems on this site.

Comment: It should be much easier to type and display math in your blogs than in an WordPress blog like mine. And I liked the design very much.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8464/discussion-between-ron-gordon-and-americo-tavares)